# nginx ssl node reverse proxy do not start

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I am trying to bind a ssl certificate to nginx but it keeps failing to start i am attaching my config file,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name appoye.com;
    return 301 https://appoye.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name appoye.com;
    root /home/rohit_jain/appoye-beta-old/dist;

    # SSL Certs
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/appoye.com/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/appoye.com/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;         
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/appoye.com-error.log error;
}
```

Nginx is still not passing my nodejs revser proxy and ssl certificate as well

Comment: You're saying "Nginx is still not passing my nodejs revser proxy and ssl certificate as well"

Does that mean you want to terminate SSL in your node.js application? Or do you want nginx to handle(terminate) the SSL?

Comment: What do you mean "failing to start"? Is there an error message? Have you tried `nginx -t` to test your configuration file?